# Access to phpmyadmin denied

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2

I just installed apache2 server php5, mysql and phpmyadmin today and I cant the access to myphpadmin through localhost/myphpadmin is denied.

I first changed the folder /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf in order to allow 127.0.0.1 see below

```
    # phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

    Alias /****** /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
        </IfModule>

        Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1

    </Directory>

[...]
```

then I also changed the rules inside /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php in order to make [AllowNoPassword]to true.

I dont know what to do in order to allow myphpadmin to access apache2?

Thank you for your response.

Comment: by default 127 and localhost has access .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you typing *localhost/myphpadmin* or *localhost/phpmyadmin*..??

Second, changing rules inside *config.sample.inc.php* won't get you anything until you rename this file to *config.inc.php*

Third, if you are doing this in order to understand how things work then it's fine but if you want to get on to some serious development then imho, you should try [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) (comes for linux and mac also) as it will free you from environment setup pains..

Comment: Thanks,this was a question of Alias

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved this issue.

So my setup is:
CentOS 8, Apache 2.4.37, phpmyadmin 5.0.4, php 8.0.0

1. I was following [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-centos-8/) guideline for installing phpmyadmin on a CentOS 8.
2. Then I have edited file phpmyadmin.conf, located in a directory /etc/httpd/conf.d

```
Alias /phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
Alias /phpmyadmin/ /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
       AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip 192.118.1.0/15
 </Directory>
```

*NOTE: My IP is like 192.118.1.123. Check it in a config...learn rules. I hope this will help to someone.